# THUMB push/pop instructions

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb

I'm trying to create a factorial method using THUMB instructions, and I'm basically there.

I just have one question about the `PUSH`/`POP` opcodes: if I stored the value of r0 in the stack using push (so `push {r0}`), can I later use `pop {r1}` to pull it out or do I need to specify the same register as it was in to begin with? Thanks for your help.

Comment: All the instructions are separate. If you wish to use push/pop to copy the previous contents of r0 to r1 you can do it.

Comment: not specific to arm, any architecture from any vendor (x86, arm, mips, etc) that allows you to specify the register/memory being pushed and register/memory that is the destination of the pop, as an assembly programmer you are free to push and pop to/from wherever you like, if the hardware had a limitation then you would not have the freedom to choose the register and you would be told what register is used.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can since `push`/`pop` actually expand to store/load multiple, which are generic instructions operating on registers and memory, so

```
push {r0}
```

is equivalent to

```
stmdb sp!, {r0}  @ or stmfd sp!, {r0} in alt notation
```

and

```
pop {r1}
```

is the same as

```
ldmia sp!, {r1}  @ or ldmfd sp!, {r1}
```

Comment: There is one caveat, arguments to push/pop/ldm/stm are in ascending register order, not in the order specified.  so if you do push{r0,r1} and then pop{r1,r0} intending to swap them, this will fail because pop{r1,r0} is identical to pop{r0,r1}

Comment: Yes, with a list of registers you have to watch out for this. Thanks @VariableLengthCoder.